# Is there any way to deal with helicopter gunships other than shooting them out of the sky?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

As far as ground vehicles go, there are lethal and non-lethal options to destroy and capture respectively.

Peace Walker had methods for dealing with helicopter gunships that would lead to capture, such as shooting the canopy open to expose the pilot, and then tranquillising them.

Does Phantom Pain also feature non-lethal options when it comes to dealing with helicopter gunships? Or is destroying them the only option?

Comment: My guess is that there were plans for similar mechanics for gunships in TPP, but they never made it in due to time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destroying them is the only option, or don't get noticed by them.

Destroying a helicopter will not count as a kill, nor add Demon Points, unless it crashes on somebody else, as the game considers the helicopter to be unmanned.

Comment: This is true of all vehicles, actually, tanks included... except that if you extract a tank, you sometimes get the soldier inside also?

Comment: @SableDreamer I believe you do get the soldiers piloting extracted ground vehicles, but it's a shame you can't do anything else with helicopters

Comment: "Destroying a helicopter will not count as a kill" - which is pretty weird, considering [you can actually shoot the pilot to take a heli down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgjep6lykoY). I don't know whether that counts as a kill, though.

Comment: @user2357112: I think it s more due to the mission, try this on another mission, and you ll not be able to even see a pilot.